# Not able to delete items from flatList In react-native from Api,ApiCard is another Component where the required data items are coming had a del buttn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

It's not deleting anything and delete action isn't working

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import {
   StyleSheet,
   View,
   FlatList,
   Text,
   TouchableOpacity,
   SafeAreaView,
   Button,
 } from 'react-native';
 import ApiCard from './ApiCard';
    
 export default class ApiList extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       loading: true,
       dataSource: [],
     };
   }
   static navigationOptions = {
     title: 'List of countries',
   };
   componentDidMount() {
     fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(responseJson => {
         this.setState({
           loading: false,
           dataSource: responseJson,
         });
       })
       .catch(error => console.log(error)); 
   }
   render() {
     const {dataSource} = this.state;
     const {navigation} = this.props;
     return (
       <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
         <FlatList
           data={dataSource}
           keyExtractor={item => item.name}
           renderItem={data => (
             <ApiCard {...data.item} navigation={navigation} />

           )}
         />
       </SafeAreaView>
     );
   }
 }
```

The below component is for data rendering as props:

```
import React from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';

const ApiCard = ({name, navigation, alpha2Code, population, capital}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.country}
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.push('CountryName', {
          name,
          alpha2Code,
          population,
          capital,
        })
      }>
      <Text>{name}</Text>
      <Text>{alpha2Code}</Text>
      <Button title="del" />
```

Here I need a del button action :

```
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default ApiCard;
```

Comment: After delete action it will re-render and dataSource will be updated with data fetched from API in which deleted entry exists. Therefore you are not getting delete action.

You can use async-storage to store array of indices of deleted entries and remove those entries after data fetching.

Comment: do you have any Sample code for async-storage??